# How do you get the content from Tinymce when the form is posted?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is how my form looks like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>צור כתבה</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
       mode : "textareas",
       theme : "advanced",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
       height:"1000px",
       width:"800px",

       editor_selector :"mceEditor"
    });



tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();


</script> 
</head>

<body>


<div align="center"  id="htmlEditor">
<form >
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <textarea name="textareas" cols="40" rows="20" class="mceEditor"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="center">
     <input type="submit"  value="צור מאמר"/>
   </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When the form is posted, I want to fetch the data that is inside the textarea as it is and put it into the database.

The question is how do I do it, considering that I use php and $_POST..

I know that there is that function: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

But it is a javascript function. How do I fetch the data from that javascript function and put into my php code so that I will be able to use it to put into my database?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you have to get it using `$_POST['textareas']` because 'textareas' is the `name` of the textarea.

The function `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` is client side, so you can get the content while you are on the page (before the submit).

Anyway as Amila said, you should add the `method="post"` to your form.

Comment: It has worked. But will it distort anything...cause they made a special function to get the content..tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd You are confusing this function which is client side, so you can get the content while you are on the page (before the submit) and the php method which is client side and it is used after the submit.

Answer (score 3):

add form method as post

```
<form method="post" action="" >
```

now you can get the textarea value by $_POST['textareas'];

Answer (score 1):

yes by using post method you will get the value of your input element and for the tinyMice the name of the element to which you have created the `instance` of the `tinyMice` in your case it's `textares`