# How to display input from TinyMCE?

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce

I successfully installed TinyMCE for text editing options for a POST form. When I recieve the text to my database it comes in HTML format. Which is fine. My question is how can I display this input back to my page or another page? To clarify... When I receive the input from the TinyMCE form field it looks like this:

```
<h1>Help</h1>
```

However, I want it to look like this:

Help

I see on stackoverflow that it will clean out the HTML tags. How can I do this to my text?

Comment: Also, tag stack-overflow is totally unrelated. Read short description before tagging please and this question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738903/how-do-you-get-the-content-from-tinymce-when-the-form-is-posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See docs: [getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.Selection.getContent)

You don't need to try to get rid of the html tags with php or else. What you should do is while you're on the page use

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : 'text'});
```

to get the content in plain text format and use it accordingly.

You didn't post any code so that's all I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use these tags

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($your_custom_variable));
```